# Sql or linq to sql Unique Constraint based on two columns value

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I don't know is it possible or not.
I have a table that keeps records for a book issue return.There are two columns in this one is [status] and other [bookid] .I want to add a constraint in sql that will restrict user to insert duplicate record for status="issue" with same bookid.

For example if there is already a record with status='issue' and bookid=1 then it must not allow to insert other record with status="issue" and bookid=1 but there can me multipule records with other status like staus='return' and bookid=1 may occur a number of times.

Or there may be solution using linq to sql in c#

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a user defined function, in general.  In SQL Server (and many other databases) you can just use a filtered index:

```
create unique index unq_bookissue
    where status = 'issued' ;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server you can do this with a computed column, assuming that you have a table with columns such as:

- `BookId`, which is repeated across rows.
- `Status`, which should be unique when the value is `issue`.
- `BookIssueId`, which uniquely identifies each row.

Then, add a computed column to keep track of `status = 'issue'`:

```
alter table t add computed_bookissueid as (case when status = 'issue' then -1 else BookIssueId end);
```

Now add a unique index on this column and `BookId`:

```
create unique index unq_bookid_issue on (BookId, computed_bookissueid);
```

Comment: thanks that's work    with a little change in syntax
create unique index unq_bookissuedReference
    on Books(book_id) where [status] = 'issued'

Answer (score 1):

You have a complex condition here, so a `UNIQUE`constraint won't help you. You will need a `CHECK`constraint.

You first need a function to to do your check:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsReturnDuplicate
(
    @id INT,
    @bookid INT,
    @status VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT (*) FROM bookreturns WHERE (id <> @id) AND (status = @status) AND (bookid = @bookid) AND (status = 'issue')
END
```

This will return 1 if there is already a row in the table that has status 'issue' and has a different id

You can then create a `CHECK` constraint using this function

```
CREATE TABLE bookreturns (
    --...
    CONSTRAINT CK_bookreturns_status CHECK (dbo.IsReturnDuplicate(id, bookid, status) == 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Gordon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692809/5621827)

```
create unique index unq_bookissuedReference
on Books(Book_id) where [status] = 'issued'
```

Works for me

Comment: Anything that works. If your unique index gets too big you can still switch to the check constraint, which will not increase DB size.

Comment: @safe I also tried your solution too and it also works fine